# how to access views of systems and user installed application in an android service?

Tags: android

i am making an application for blinds for which i have to write my own talkback services. the problem i am facing is I WANT TO ACCESS VIEWS OF SYSTEM INSTALLED APPLICATIONS AND AS WELL AS USER INSTALLED APPLICATIONS SO THAT I CAN MAKE MY APP SPEAK EVERYTHING WHICH IS TOUCHED BY USER.
please help me in this problem.

REGARDS

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to implement an [accessibility service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html).

Comment: Accessibilty donot allows you to make a gesture with a single touch you have to use two fingers to draw something. My basic problem is i want to draw a gesture using a single finger while an accessibility service ON.